# How to capture regions flanking string region in Perl?

Tags: perl, substr

I'm wondering if there is any Perl function that acts as inverse of `substr`. If `substr` selects a part of the string defined by coordinates, this function skips this part and instead captures string parts flanking given coordinates.

It can be just done using `substr` with coordinates I want for each flank, but I was wondering if there is something built-in for such cases.

Comment: Could you give a concrete example, please? ("For these inputs, I'd expect this output")

Answer (score 3):

Easiest and fastest way is probably to use four-parameter substring.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $orig    = 'aaabbbccc';

my $middle  = substr( $orig, 3, 3 );

substr( my $flanks = $orig, 3, 3, '/' );

say $orig;    # aaabbbccc
say $middle;  # bbb
say $flanks;  # aaa/ccc
```

If you don't want the slash in the output, then `substr( my $flanks = $orig, 3, 3, '' )`.

Answer (score 2):

This can be handled with [`substr()`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/substr), if you add some Perl logic. `substr()` can be used to delete part of a string by adding an empty string as REPLACEMENT, as denoted in the [documentation](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/substr):

> substr EXPR,OFFSET,LENGTH,**REPLACEMENT**

For example, you can do this:

```
my $org = "foo bar baz";
my $flank = $org;
my $mid = substr($flank, 4, 3, '');
print "Original: $org\nMid: $mid\nFlank: $flank\n";
```

Which will print this:

```
Original: foo bar baz
Mid: bar
Flank: foo  baz
```